# How do I stop these DIVs from creating a horizontal scroll bar on the browser viewport?

Tags: css

I've got the following CSS declarations on some DIVs on a page:

```
position:relative;
box-sizing:border-box;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
padding: 10%;
```

I'm pretty new to using both the `vw` scaling unit, and to using `calc()`, so I may be missing something obvious.

The intent is that even though the DIVs are nested inside other DIVs, they extend beyond their parent to cover the width of the entire viewport. It works *nearly* perfectly. At least, it does in Firefox 37.

The problem is that these DIVs end up sized just ever so slightly bigger than the width of the viewport, by just a few pixels, enough to cause a horizontal scroll bar to appear at the bottom of the viewport. I've tried making adjustments, such as using `99vw` for width, or adjusting the `calc()` values up and down, but I'm just shooting in the dark and I can't seem to dial it in.

There must be some nuance to the calculations here that I'm not seeing. How can I ensure my DIVs are exactly as wide as the viewport, no bigger, no smaller, and without forcing any horizontal scroll bars?

Comment: Can you add a demo fiddle reproducing this?

Comment: "they extend beyond their parent to cover", i'd suggest against this but can you provide us with a code sample?

Comment: @anpsmn, I'm trying to recreate this, but I can't seem to. If I could figure out why it's working on JSFiddle but not on my site, I'll have probably worked out my own problem.

Comment: @Questioner Oh ok. Can you add the HTML to the question also a screenshot of how exactly it looks?

Comment: @Questioner : If it works in JSFiddle but not your website, there's probably some extra styling added to your element(s) which led to the problem but you haven't realized.

Comment: @Billy, I'm sure you're right, but right now I'm climbing up and down the code and I just can't find it. I'm trying to rebuild everything step by step, but... the only thing I've learned is that if I apply `margin:0 -.7vh;` then that fixes it. It's a kludge, though, so I'm hoping I can figure something out.